# Forget to reset parameter for production version

Tags: delphi, components, delphi-2009

I use TAdoconnection to access the database. 
During development i set the connectionstring to my local database and set connected to true in order to get the information for the other dbcomponents.

When I finalize the program for a customer I forget sometimes to reset the parameter, which leads to an exception on the customer computer because the connectionstring is invalid.

I tried to put in the oncreate event of the datamodule (first line) a connected:=false but it seems to late.
How can I make sure that it the program has the rigth settings for the customer? 
I tried to set some parameter in in a conditional compiling phrase like:

```
{$IFDEF PRODUCT}
param1:=..
....
{$ENDIF}
```

But I have no clue how to do this for visual components.

Comment: No conditional code in dfm files. Just don't commit you dev settings to the revision control system. Presumably you always review changes before committing?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I don't really use a revision control system; my system is called windows folders with a special back up functionality. In prior projects I had some contact with some systems, but I never saw the posibility to "strip" my development settings from the source code

Comment: It's not really software development without revision control.

Comment: You'll be doing yourself a huge favour if you use a version control system. At a minimum, you can configure a local [git](https://git-scm.com/) for free. You can even sign up to github for simple offsite backup. (Also free if you don't mind your repository being public.)

Comment: That said. A simpler solution to your problem is: make sure your dev environment runs in the same way as production. I.e. Don't rely on design-time active connections to do your dev. You can go a step further; if you accidentally leave a connection active (e.g. because you opened a table to preview in a grid), you can easily detect this and report the error. That way, provided you always run your app at least _once_ before cutting a new prod version, you're unlikely to make the mistake of releasing with a connection active at design time.

Comment: @Craig Young, don't understand me wrong, I'm not against a version control. In former projects I got experience with MKS and Subversion, but from my experience both of them could not prevent my situation. Naturally we use virtual machines to test our software before it leaves, but when the customer cries at the telefon and wants immidiate relieve...

Comment: Change control practices would alert you to having made a mistake.

Comment: Have you perhaps considered using of Delphis pre-build event to execute special script which will modify the dfm file which stores the property settings of your TADOconection?

Comment: @SilverWarior No, never heared about that, can you give me please more details where to look and learn.

Comment: @ChristineRoss Oh pardon me it seems I forgot to add the link to the documentation. You can find some info here: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Build_Events

Comment: @SilverWarior: Sorry, I can't see how your proposal could work. I found a limitation in the description: "Commands consist of any valid DOS command,"

Comment: @ChristineRoss As I sad you use Pre-Build event to execute specially writen script. Now this script won't be executed from within delphi but from some external scripting enviroment. Which one depends on which scripting language will you use. But if you want you can make yourself a tiny program (tool) that will do the necessary modification to the DFM file yourself. So in the end in the pre-build event you just execute your program (tool).

Comment: @Silver A pre build script that changes code would be bad in terms of QA. You should be able to see what you built in your RCS. A pre build script that made the build fail would be acceptable.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I know this is not the best solution that is why I'm only discussing about this in the comments. The best solution would be to avoid having active database connection during the design time in the first place as it could lead to many other problems than the one Christina is facing. On older versions of delphi (Delphi 6 if my memory serves me correctly) this could even lead to project of being sucsessfully loaded into the IDE if for some reason database conection could not be established.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set true ConnectionString at runtime on event TADOConnection.OnBeforeConnect:

```
procedure TDM1.ADO1BeforeConnect(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ADO1.ConnectionString := 'Provider=SQLOLEDB;......';
end;
```

Or you can delay connecting

```
var CanConnect: Boolean;
procedure TDM1.ADO1BeforeConnect(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not CanConnect then Abort;
end;
```

Comment: It seems to me that the asker wants to be able to set properties at design time.

Comment: It seem for me the most promising solution to use beforeconnect or setconnected

Comment: @Christine Do you want to have the connection string set at design time or not?

Comment: I set the connection string during run time, because I allow the user to use more than one database, so the database can be changed. I also use an INI-File to store the actual database name. I don't like to mix internal information with customer information in the INI-File. I don't provide an INI-file with my application, it will be created on user site.

Comment: According to the question you are concerned about designtime settings. Can you understand my confusion?

Comment: I tried the beforeconnect solution and it works fine. I create an exception and everyone is informed about the problem. So this is in the moment the favourite solution. I don't forget your recommendations regarding a version control system

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use conditionals if dfm files. Which means that if you set properties at design time, then they will be applied at run time, unconditionally.

If you must avoid shipping software with certain properties set, then you must simply stop yourself from doing that. A programmatic solution at run time is not an option.

Personally I would use my version control process to help. Whenever I commit changes I review all the changes. I'd have it is part of my routine to check dfm changes.

On top of that I'd test the software before releasing it. This testing needs to be done in a clean room setting. You'll want a virtual machine snapshot that is representative of the target deployment environment. Testing on your development machine is clearly not a viable option.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, a source control system could help detect changes to your .DFM files, however, there are also some other tools/ideas at your disposal.

Here are a couple of ideas that will not affect your current deployment procedures too much:

**1) Connected property**: GExperts [GExperts](http://www.gexperts.org/) includes an IDE add-in that can detect open connections at compile-time, and automatically set the connected property to false for you.  At a minimum, you could use the tool to detect and change manually, or let the tool do it for you.  The feature can be found on the GExperts menu: Configuration, Set Component Properties, then add TAdoConnection, Property: Connected, Value: false.

**2) ConnectionString:** Move your connection string to an .ini file or registry, and have two values, one for development and one for production.  Within your code, set each based on a flag, or use:

```
 if debughook <> 0 then
   // fetch design-time connection string
 else
   // fetch production connection string
```

I would also suggest you look into automating your build process using software such as FinalBuilder.